# ¿por que ansible se ejecuta en un servidor si ya cambiaron su contraseña?

Tags: python, ansible

```
playbook cualquiera y archivo de inventario cualquiera
```

lo que sucede es que una vez ejecute un playbook con las credenciales de un servidor (su contraseña cambia aleatoriamente cada 12 horas) pero después de que se cambia la contraseña ansible aun es capaz de ejecutar el playbook aunque la contraseña del archivo de inventario sea antiguo y cuando quiero acceder mediante ssh al mismo servidor de manera manual me niega el acceso (ya que la contraseña es antigua). estuve buscando la razón pero no encuentro nada.

¿alguien sabe a que se debe?

Gracias por leer.

Comment: No conozco ansible, ¿los archivos tienen contraseñas? *aunque la contraseña del archivo de inventario sea antiguo*

Answer (score 1):

Difícil de decir exactamente con tan poca información y absolutamente sin datos de depuración. Las dos razones obvias en las que puedo pensar y es posible que desee verificar:

1. En realidad está usando una clave ssh y no un usuario/contraseña para conectarse al servidor
2. Tiene un tiempo de espera muy largo (es decir, más de 12 horas) configurado para la sesión maestra ssh y está reutilizando la conexión anterior exitosa aunque la contraseña ha cambiado.

Comment: Al no saber nada es muy difícil dar una respuesta, por eso se le deja un comentario al OP pidiendo que explique mejor el problema